# Enter full-screen when rotate the device in xamarin form (ios)

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I created native IOS av-player in Xamarin forms. every thing works fine but I need video-player should enter full-screen when user rotates the phone. I tried many solution nothing helps me.

currently is tried this

```
void DeviceRotated(NSNotification notification)
    {
        string rotaion = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation.ToString();

        if (rotaion == "LandscapeLeft")
        {
          _playerViewController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.BlurOverFullScreen;
           UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow();
           UIViewController rootViewController = window.RootViewController;
           _playerViewController.PresentModalViewController(rootViewController, true);
         }
    
    }
```

this didn't help me.
I can understand swift code as well.if any have good answer please share with me.

Comment: You can try to use `View.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation(-1.57079f);"` like this thread to make the AVPlayer enter to the full-screen. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54486/avplayer-fullscreen

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT can't i use EntersFullScreenWhenPlaybackBegins  this property get it my work done . i tried this still no positive result

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT i tried your link . screen rotates but not enters to full-screen . when i rotate the device to Poirot display come to back to normal size . example youtube

Comment: It seems you have an mistake in your code since the last line should be `rootViewController.PresentModalViewController(_playerViewController, true);`

Comment: @iUrii thanks chap ,its working for content page but I'm running the video player on top of   model view in Xamarin forms . above code set is not working model view ... do you have any idea about it ....

Comment: The easiest way to make your video player fullscreen with the current window or root view controller is to add one on them e.g:  `_playerViewController.view.frame =  UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds; rootViewController.view.addSubview(_playerViewController.view); ` or `window.addSubview(_playerViewController.view); `

Comment: this helps  get full screen in  portrait view but video is not playing